# States don't work for a block rendering a form

Tags: 8, forms

I created a block in which I called a form inside the build() function.
The form class has elements like radio button, input field type number, and submit button. I added a state condition to make the number field and submit button only visible on a certain condition of radio button.

The submission button is working correctly based on state condition, but not the number input field.

Does anyone has any idea?

```php
$form['age'] = [
  '#type' => 'number',
  '#min' => 0,
  '#title' => $this->t('age'),
  '#default_value' =>'',
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      [':input[name="marital_status"]' => [['value' => 'single'],['value'=>'couple']]],
    ]
  ],
];

$form['mybutton'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('button'),
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      [':input[name="marital_status"]' => [['value' => 'single'],['value'=>'couple']]],
    ]
  ],
];

$form['marital_status'] = [
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => $this->t('Marital status'),
  '#options' => [
    'single' => $this->t('single'),
    'couple' => $this->t('couple')
  ]
];
```

Comment: I don't think you can have an array of arrays with values for conditions to work. Make it look more like https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states and simply repeat the line and have one value per line or try `=> ['value' => 'single','value'=>'couple']],`.

Comment: @leymannx thanks, I tried but it did not work, one condition was missing as well, actually It is an or condition. It seems like something is overriding the state conditions

Answer (score 0):

I had to override the twig files for the form-element so some classes were missing like js-form-item' and 'form-item'. After adding thoses classes in the twig file,  the states worked.